# How to get the validators detail information

Tags: polkadot-js

As a developer，I want to use the interface to search this information: which can get the validator detail information like the count of  nominators and the commission  and others information,

Answer (score 1):

Everything that can be read onchain is listed [here](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/storage#staking).

For example, to read the commission:

```
console.log((await api.query.staking.validators("11uMPbeaEDJhUxzU4ZfWW9VQEsryP9XqFcNRfPdYda6aFWJ")).commission)
```

Which is a [`Perbill`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sp_arithmetic/per_things/struct.Perbill.html), fixed point parts per billion, and `11uMPbeaEDJhUxzU4ZfWW9VQEsryP9XqFcNRfPdYda6aFWJ` is a totally arbitrary validator of Polkadot today.

You can directly paste this into https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#/js.

To get the count of active nominator who end up backing a validator in era:

```
const lastEra = (await api.query.staking.currentEra()).unwrap();
const exposures = await api.query.staking.erasStakers(lastEra, "11uMPbeaEDJhUxzU4ZfWW9VQEsryP9XqFcNRfPdYda6aFWJ");
console.log(exposures.others.length)
```

To get the list of all the nominators who casted a vote for `11uMPbeaEDJhUxzU4ZfWW9VQEsryP9XqFcNRfPdYda6aFWJ`, you have to iterate the [`nominators`](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/storage#nominatorsaccountid32-optionpalletstakingnominations) map, but I will leave that up to you to figure out.

Comment: why i  search the exposures.others.length not same as the expore show ? exposures.others.length=302 but the the expore show 342

Comment: should i use currentEra or activeEra?

Comment: I think it is best if you ask the difference between currentEra and activeEra in a new question and we will answer it there.